# Kony : access a host name from android device

Tags: temenos-quantum

i'm using kony mobile fabric i'm trying to access the hostname `http://youxel--tech:8080/mfconsole`
from my android device but it says `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`it randomly works and randomly stops working is there anyone has an idea about solving this issue

Comment: this issue happens with PCs too

Comment: I would try to do following things.  1. Access with https and corresponding port number.  2. Reach out to firewall team and see if they are blocking me from reaching the server 3. Open chrome developer console and see what if it prints any errors. 4. Check middleware logs 5. If none of it works then open Kony ticket